# How to scrollTop a famo.us/angular fa-scroll-view to index 0 on click?

Tags: angularjs, scrollview, famo.us

Code sample:

```
<fa-scroll-view>

  <fa-view fa-index="0">
     surface1
   </fa-view> 

  <fa-view fa-index="1">
        surface2
  </fa-view> 

</fa-scroll-view>
```

i created the scrollView in my partial and i want to scrollTop to index 0 of the scrollview when i click a button...i found how to do it in famo.us in the link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/markmarijnissen/t2z4Q/42/

but i couldn't map the fa-scroll-view with a new Scrollview object. i don't know how can i control famo.us/angular object as it's famo.us...thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
$famous.find('fa-scroll-view')[0].renderNode.setPosition()
```

Make sure you $inject $famous into your controller